# no se puedo ejecutar los endpoints en Swagger ui v3

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

estoy migrando a Springboot 3.1.5 con JDK 17 y `openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0`, todo me funciona bien excepto swagger v3 ui, al ejecutar los endpoints me pide iniciar sesion(adjunto imagen) por lo que 42C scan falla.
Aclarar que al testear con mi api UI o postman funcionan todos los endpoints sin ningun problema. espero puedan ayudarme

[image: esto pasa cuando ejecuto un endpoints]

Comment: tienes algún código para configurar los accesos con spring security?